# How can I create cloud context.Context from appengine.Context

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I can't figure out how to call `cloud.WithContext` and `google.DefaultClient` if I have `appengine.Context` and not `context.Context`.

There are (old) "appengine" and (new) "google.golang.org/appengine" packages. The first one brings custom `appengine.Context` when second one comes with `context.Context` from `"golang.org/x/net/context"`

The whole `google.golang.org/cloud` expects `context.Context` only.

I would be happy to move to using new `"google.golang.org/appengine"`, but I've stuck with `runtime.RunInBackground` that have not been ported yet. From https://github.com/golang/appengine:

> `appengine/aetest`, `appengine/cloudsql` and `appengine/runtime` have not been ported yet.

What I could write if `appengine/runtime` have been ported already:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/net/context"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/runtime"
    "google.golang.org/cloud"
    "google.golang.org/cloud/storage"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    runtime.RunInBackground(c, func(ctx context.Context) {
        hc, _ := google.DefaultClient(ctx, storage.ScopeFullControl)
        cc := cloud.WithContext(ctx, appengine.AppID(ctx), hc)
        …
   })
}
```

but there is no `"google.golang.org/appengine/runtime"` yet. So I have

```
runtime.RunInBackground(c, func(ctx appengine.Context) {
```

Comment: If I make a trick with `oauth2.NoContext` I get an error "not an App Engine context"

Comment: There is function `BackgroundContext() context.Context` but it's intended for managed vm only https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/appengine_vm.go#L30 It seems like I should use Managed VM for my task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to get cloud `context.Context` from (old) `appengine.Context`.

**Solution for Managed VM**

A month ago `BackgroundContext()` method [was added](https://github.com/golang/appengine/commit/61bec684bd7bce2d7960be6735d0d62fe6c2b99a) to `google.golang.org/appengine` (available for Managed VM only). This allows start goroutine and get cloud `context.Context` without passing it into.

**Solution for classic Appengine**

There is no solution at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
func getCloudContext(appengineContext context.Context) context.Context {
    hc := &http.Client{
        Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
            Source: google.AppEngineTokenSource(appengineContext, storage.ScopeFullControl),
            Base:   &urlfetch.Transport{Context: appengineContext},
        },
    }

    return cloud.NewContext(appengine.AppID(appengineContext), hc)
}
```

Or if passing the credentials through the dev server isn't working, you can also use explicit credentials:

```
func getCloudContext(aeCtx context.Context) (context.Context, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/credentials.json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(
        data,
        storage.ScopeFullControl,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    tokenSource := conf.TokenSource(aeCtx)

    hc := &http.Client{
        Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
            Source: tokenSource,
            Base:   &urlfetch.Transport{Context: aeCtx},
        },
    }

    return cloud.NewContext(appengine.AppID(aeCtx), hc), nil
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want to make background work and can't pass context.Context through runtime.RunInBackground(c, func(ctx appengine.Context)  call. It's only appengine.Context can pass over

Comment: Can you use the delay package? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay. The newer libraries have a context.Context: http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/delay

Comment: No, I need to run goroutine on the same instance. It should flush buffered data to Cloud Storage

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do what you want:

```
import (
    "code.google.com/p/goauth2/appengine/serviceaccount"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "appengine"
)

// oauth2 module requires a context.Context so use goauth2 for now
func CloudContext(c appengine.Context, scopes ...string) context.Context {
    client, _ := serviceaccount.NewClient(c, scopes...)
    return cloud.WithContext(context.Background(), appengine.AppID(c), client)
}
```

You can get the goauth2 library from https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/

Comment: 1) Sorry, but code.google.com is deprecated as a whole and code.google.com/p/goauth2 in particular (it's said to use https://github.com/golang/oauth2 that have no clue about "appengine")

Comment: 2) Sorry, your second option get "not an App Engine context" on attempt to write to Cloud Storage

Comment: 1) Yes it is deprecated, but does it work?  You can find the library at https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/

Comment: It does not matter if deprecated code works or not. I won't use it in a new project.